# How do you attach client data to the server connection?

Tags: meteor

I'm imagining something like this:

```
# client
Meteor.call 'attachData', localStorage.getItem 'clientData'

Meteor.connection.onReconnect ->
  Meteor.call 'attachData', localStorage.getItem 'clientData'

setTimeout ->
  Meteor.call 'logData'
, 1000

# server
Meteor.methods
  attachData: (data) ->
    this.connection.data = data

  logData: ->
    console.log this.connection.data
```

This seems to be working, but I'm unfamiliar with `this.connection`. Given this setup, will `this.connection.data` always be there? Should I be using `Meteor.connection` or `Meteor.default_connection`?

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish? by not just keep that data in a collection where you use the connection id as a key?

Comment: I'm using an API that uses a temporary per-client-user access token. Since the data is temporary and not needed by other app servers, it seems more efficient for it to be saved in the app server's memory than in the DB. It's also part of a package, and would be simpler for the package user than eg supplying a collection or field name in package config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to work. The data is deleted when connection is broken, either by page reload or break in internet connection.

https://github.com/lorensr/connection-data